# How to log the exception information while using the ResponseStatusException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using both the `ExceptionAdvice` and `ResponseStatusException` to handle the exception situation in my web application. Now I'd like to log the exception information while throwing the `ResponseStatusException` in my Controller class.

I can always write the log code near the line that throw the exception in my Controller class:

```java
controllerMethod(){
    logger.error("some thing happens here!");
    throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN, "some reason");
}
```

But writing code all over the place is too tedious, In fact, i'd like some pattern that i used in my `ExceptionAdvice` class:

```java
@ResponseBody
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
String myExceptionHandler(MyException e){
    logger.error("oops!", e);
    return "something";
}
```

However, the `ReponseStatusException` response that Spring generated has the format which i want to maintain like:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-02-01T04:28:32.917+0000",
    "status": 400,
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Provide correct Actor Id",
    "path": "/actor/8/BradPitt"
}
```

So is there anyway that i can use advice class to log for the `ResponseStatusException` while still maintaining its generated response, or, on the contrast, using other class to add log ability around all the `ReponseStatusException` without typing the `logger.error` everywhere that the exception is thrown?

Answer (score 8):

You can enable the logging with the property

```
spring.mvc.log-resolved-exception=true
```

involved classes are

- WebMvcAutoConfiguration
- AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver
- ResponseStatusExceptionResolver

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to do it (tested in Spring Boot 2.3.3).

Create a class that extends `ResponseStatusExceptionResolver`:

```java
    /**
     * Extended implementation that adds logging of {@link ResponseStatusException}s.
     * <p>
     * Note: {@link #setMessageSource(MessageSource)} has to be called if reason is a message code, rather than a message itself
     */
    private static class LoggingResponseStatusExceptionResolver extends ResponseStatusExceptionResolver {
        @Override
        protected ModelAndView resolveResponseStatus(ResponseStatus responseStatus, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
            log(responseStatus.code(), responseStatus.reason(), ex);
            return super.resolveResponseStatus(responseStatus, request, response, handler, ex);
        }

        @Override
        protected ModelAndView resolveResponseStatusException(ResponseStatusException ex, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
            log(ex.getStatus(), ex.getReason(), ex);
            return super.resolveResponseStatusException(ex, request, response, handler);
        }

        private void log(HttpStatus status, String reason, Exception exception) {
            if (status.isError()) {
                logger.error(status + ": " + reason + "\n", exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in one of your application configuration classes implement `WebMvcConfigurer` and replace the default resolver with the extended one:

```
    @Override
    public void extendHandlerExceptionResolvers(List<HandlerExceptionResolver> resolvers) {
        resolvers.replaceAll(resolver ->
                resolver instanceof ResponseStatusExceptionResolver
                        ? new LoggingResponseStatusExceptionResolver()
                        : resolver
        );
    }
```